# ¿Como realizo una consulta a los usuarios sys,system,scott? en oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

¿Cómo puedo realizar una consulta de los admin predeterminados que tiene el oracle 11g?

Si utilizo el

```
 select count(1) from all_Tables;
```

Me sale el conteo total de las tablas, más no a cual corresponde cada una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener una lista de las tablas con el usuario propietario:

```
select owner, table_name
  from all_tables
 order by owner, table_name ;
```

Si, en cambio, quieres saber cuantas tablas tiene cada uno:

```
select owner, count(1)
  from all_tables
 group by owner;
```

Esto te listará las tablas que están accesibles para el usuario con el que corre la consulta.